# How to make a new dataframe with aggregated column values in R that is grouped by another column

Tags: r, group-by, aggregate, dplyr

I have used dplyr before to add an aggregated column with success, but I am not sure how to create a new wide dataframe that contains new aggregated columns (mean values) based on the values of another column (SkillGroup) and grouped by another column (EmployeeID).

My original DF looks like this:

```
EmployeeID <- c(rep(1,5), rep(2,3))
SkillGroup <- c(rep("A",3), rep("B",2), "A", "B", "C")
Proficiency <- c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3)
mydata <- data.frame(EmployeeID, SkillGroup, Proficiency)
```

The final dataframe that I'm interested in looks like this:

```
EmployeeID2 <- c(1,2)
MeanSkillA <- c(2,1)
MeanSkillB <- c(4.5,2)
MeanSkillC <- c(NA, 3)
desiredDF <- data.frame(EmployeeID2, MeanSkillA, MeanSkillB, MeanSkillC)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregate values and then `tidyr::spread`:

```
mydata %>% 
    group_by(EmployeeID, SkillGroup = paste('MeanSkill', SkillGroup, sep="")) %>% 
    summarise(MeanSkill = mean(Proficiency)) %>% 
    spread(SkillGroup, MeanSkill)

# A tibble: 2 x 4
# Groups:   EmployeeID [2]
#  EmployeeID MeanSkillA MeanSkillB MeanSkillC
#*      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
#1          1          2        4.5         NA
#2          2          1        2.0          3
```